# uwp commandbar always show label

Tags: user-interface, uwp, commandbar

**Answer:**

Thanks to [Justin XL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231837/justin-xl) I was able to fix my problem.

I implemented the style he provided below in his answer and added, as he said, this in the App.xaml: ( I changed the height to 66 - fits better for me)

```
<Application.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="AppBarThemeCompactHeight">66</x:Double>
    </Application.Resources>
```

and then this in my `CommandBar`

```
Height="{StaticResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"
```

---

**Question:**

I want my Command Bar to always show its Labels, in standard mode. I have Secondary Commands so `IsOpen=true` is not an option for me.

[image]

Right now I just see the Icons and no labels underneath.

The official Microsoft Site for Command Bar says this:

> The app bar button controls are characterized by an icon and
>   associated label. They have two sizes; normal and compact. By default,
>   the text label is shown. When the IsCompact property is set to true,
>   the text label is hidden. When used in a CommandBar control, the
>   command bar overwrites the button's IsCompact property automatically
>   as the command bar is opened and closed.

This kinda is an issue. Any ideas how I can make `IsCompact=False` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by editing the default style of the `AppBarButton`.

[image: Working demo]

First, generate the default style using Blend, then locate the **Compact** visual state and change the `Visibility` target value form `Collapsed` to `Visible`. This way no matter what the `IsCompact` value is, the label will always be visible.

```
<Style x:Key="FullHeightAppBarButtonStyle"
               TargetType="AppBarButton">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                    Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                    Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="68" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction"
                    Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle"
                                       TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Width"
                                            Value="NaN" />
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Visible" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="12,14,0,14" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="0" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="1" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Left" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="8,15,12,17" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Visible" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="Visible" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding"
                                                    Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding"
                                                    Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot"
                                  MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                  Height="20"
                                                  Margin="0,14,0,4" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                           Margin="2,0,2,6"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Margin="12,0,12,0"
                                       Padding="0,5,0,7"
                                       TextAlignment="Left"
                                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                       TextTrimming="Clip"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

After applying the above style to all your buttons, there's one more thing you will need to do. At the moment the label is cut off due to the height of the `CommandBar` in *compact* mode. You will want to increase it so the label can fit in. There's a simple way to do this as I detailed it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465394/change-height-of-bottom-appbar-in-xaml-uwp/42713307#42713307). In your case, you will want to set the height to `76` (as the height of the `AppBarButton` will be `76`).