# Always visible toolbar item labels on UWP/Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, toolbar

I'd like to configure the toolbar on UWP/Xamarin such that labels underneath toolbar items were always visible (see: [uwp commandbar always show label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456038/uwp-commandbar-always-show-label), bottom image).

The problem is that the application is written in Xamarin Forms and the toolbar seem to be integral part of the page, so the only solution, which comest to my mind would be to write some kind of custom renderer for page and try to access the command bar from there. Or is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Does the following answer work ?

Answer (score 1):

> Always visible toolbar item labels on UWP/Xamarin

You have no need custom renderer, Derive from the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Platform.cs#L414). The `ToolbarItem` was renderer with `AppBarButton` in uwp platform. So you could use Justin XL provided `AppBarButton` style in the uwp App.Xaml file, For making  the style global, please remove `x:key` value and then set `AppBarThemeCompactHeight` as 60.  The following code is complete the you can use directly.

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <x:Double x:Key="AppBarThemeCompactHeight">60</x:Double>
    <Style TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="68" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="Root"
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="Content"
                                Height="20"
                                Margin="0,14,0,4"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                />
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="TextLabel"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="2,0,2,6"
                                FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                />
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                            Margin="12,0,12,0"
                            Padding="0,5,0,7"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            TextTrimming="Clip"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```