# UWP CommandBar has gap at the bottom

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use a CommandBar at the bottom of my UWP app, but I can't seem to get rid of this gap at the bottom.

[image]

It's quite hard to see but it's there between the CommandBar and the bottom border of the window. I've tried all sorts of `VerticalAlignment` configurations but nothing seems to do it. I've created a user control

```html
<UserControl
    x:Class="PivotalTrackerUWP.Controls.NavigationControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PivotalTrackerUWP.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:svg="using:Mntone.SvgForXaml.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="50"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <CommandBar Height="50">
                <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                    <AppBarButton  Label="Preferences"/>
                    <AppBarSeparator/>
                    <AppBarButton Label="My Account"/>
                    <AppBarButton Label="Logout" Click="LogoutButton_Click"/>
                </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            </CommandBar>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am then using this control in my other XAML pages within the main Grid at the bottom.When in the designer for this UserControl there is also still that gap at the bottom so I think it's something with the XAML in the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the hard coded `Height=50` on your `CommandBar`, which has a default compact height of `48`.

If you want to customize this default height, have a look my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465394/change-height-of-bottom-appbar-in-xaml-uwp/42713307#42713307). But for *two pixels* difference, it's probably worth following the default style for a more consistent look across the OS.

Also, you don't need to specify `Height` for your `Grid` too. It will simply stretch to whatever its children need. So just remove `Heigjt=50` in there.

**However**, the best way to display a *bottom* `CommandBar` though, is to follow this format -

```
<Page x:Class="App1.MainPage" ...>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Grid/>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="AppBarButton"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="AppBarButton"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This will ensure it's positioned at the bottom of the page. To add a *top* `CommandBar`, use `Page.TopAppBar` instead.

Comment: This would work brilliantly, but I'm using a Usercontrol for the sake of code re-use, I don't really want to be adding the XAML for the BottomAppBar on every single page.

Comment: If that's the case, you can either refer to my linked answer to give the command bar a different compact height in App.Xaml, or simply remove all the hard coded height values.

Comment: I used the solution in your linked answer and it works a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Background** property and default style for **CommandBar** (*SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush*):

```
 <Grid Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <CommandBar Height="50">
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton  Label="Preferences"/>
                <AppBarSeparator/>
                <AppBarButton Label="My Account"/>
                <AppBarButton Label="Logout" Click="LogoutButton_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`CommandBar` doesn't have a bottom vertical alignment, and its height is lower than the height of its container so it is expected to render like that.

Other than that, why do you use the `CommandBar` just to show three dots, wouldn't it be more efficient/better looking to use a `Button` there with a 'More' SymbolIcon and have `MenuFlyout` attached?